# USB mouse cord connection name

Tags: usb, mouse, hardware-rec

I'm planning on modifying my USB gaming mouse to add a micro USB port instead of the cable coming out of it currently because it has gone bad (the mouse stops working when the cable is in certain positions).  I'm having trouble finding a premade cable at most 3 - 6 inches that has the internal usb connection to micro usb.  Partly, I believe, because i don't know what the connection is called.

Does anyone know what the name of that connection is? it's a smaller usb connection that seems to be standard on most usb mice. The one in bottom left hand corner.

[image: http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-Original-For-Razer-Naga-Molten-Naga-Hex-Naga-2012-Mouse-USB-Cable-USB-Line-/251702768161?_trksid=p2141725.m3641.l6390]

Comment: pictures might help - though a new mouse would be a whole lot less trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats a USB header, although i'm not sure if the different headers have specific names